# Unable to get the index whenever the list elements output as true

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a code which will update the groups list as 1 whenever it finds a match. The comparison is done element by element from list inp and list a. The groups list displays the output properly but I am unable to access individual list elements. I want to identify which all indexes gives output as True when I apply function as all(groups)

```py
def zerolistmaker(n):
    listofzeros = [0] * n
    return listofzeros

inp=['6161', '03901', '81750', 'BRIN', '610415', 'WADD', '045211', '041577']
a=[['JOSH', 'M', 'WADD', ' ', '41577', '041577'], ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', '045211', '045211'], ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', '81750', '6161'], ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', 'None', '610415770488']]
stopwords=[' ','None']
for i in a:
    #print(i)
    while(' ' in i) : 
        i.remove(' ') 
    while('None' in i) : 
        i.remove('None') 
    #.remove('None')
    #print(i)

    groups=zerolistmaker(len(i))
    #print(groups)
    for k in range(0,len(i)):
        for j in range(0,len(inp)):
            if i[k] == inp[j]:
                #print("String match: ",i[k])
                groups[k]= 1
    print(groups)
    t=[all(groups)]
    print(t)
```

Actual output of print(groups):

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
```

When I try to execute `print(groups[3])`, it is taking the 3rd column vertically as 1,1,1,0. I want to iterate the groups list as group[0] output as below and then I need to apply all function to each list. Convert the groups to 2D list as `[[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],[1, 1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 1], [1 ,1 0]]`
If possible something like below:

```
for i in groups:
    if all(groups[i])==True:
         print("perfect match")
    else:
        print("mismatch in records")
```

Please suggest what am I doing wrong in this code, any improvisation to achieve the result in a better way is appreciated.

Comment: This is unclear. `groups` is a 1-dimensional list whose elements are either 0 or 1. `all(groups[0])` is thus either `all(0)` or `all(1)`, neither of which make sense.

Comment: @John for ```t=all(groups)```, I get output as ```False,True,False,True```. But I want to understand at what index am I getting the value as True.

Comment: `t.index(True)` will give you the first index at which `t` is `True`

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are trying to do. Your  `groups` is a purely 1-dimensional data structure but you seem to be thinking of it as 2-dimensional  (for example, you referred to "columns", but lists don't have columns). Perhaps you want `groups` to be a list of lists rather than a list of integers.

Comment: @John,my first doubt is in what way should I access the groups list, so that I can get output as ```groups[0]=[0, 0, 1, 0, 1], groups[1]=[1,1,1]``` and so on. After that I want to apply all(groups[0]), all(groups[1])...and so on. Something like below ```for i in groups: if all(groups[i])==True: print("match found") else: print("record mismatch")```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the following code creates the `groups` that you want:

```
inp=['6161', '03901', '81750', 'BRIN', '610415', 'WADD', '045211', '041577']
a=[['JOSH', 'M', 'WADD', ' ', '41577', '041577'], ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', '045211', '045211'], ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', '81750', '6161'], ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', 'None', '610415770488']]
stopwords=[' ','None']

wordlists = [[w for w in words if not w in stopwords] for words in a] #cleanup a
groups = [[1 if word in inp else 0 for word in wordlist] for wordlist in wordlists]
```

To test it:

```
for group in groups:
    print(group)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0]
```

In terms of your original code, here is a fix with minimal changes. The main idea is to define `groups` *outside* of the main loop and append the smaller lists to it (rather than merely printing them, which doesn't save them):

```
def zerolistmaker(n):
    listofzeros = [0] * n
    return listofzeros

inp=['6161', '03901', '81750', 'BRIN', '610415', 'WADD', '045211', '041577']
a=[['JOSH', 'M', 'WADD', ' ', '41577', '041577'], ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', '045211', '045211'], ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', '81750', '6161'], ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', 'None', '610415770488']]
stopwords=[' ','None']
groups = [] #change1
for i in a:
    while(' ' in i) : 
        i.remove(' ') 
    while('None' in i) : 
        i.remove('None') 

    group=zerolistmaker(len(i))
    for k in range(0,len(i)):
        for j in range(0,len(inp)):
            if i[k] == inp[j]:
                group[k]= 1 #change2
    groups.append(group) #change3


#test:
for group in groups:
    print(group)
```

Comment: Thank you so much , you have simplified it to a great extent.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried rewriting your code in a more idiomatic Python style. In particular, I renamed some variables, made use of [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) instead of lists where appropriate, and used [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It's a bit hard to tell what your goal is, though, so this might not be what you're after.

```py
whitelist = {
    '6161', '03901', '81750', 'BRIN', '610415', 'WADD', '045211', '041577'
}

lists_of_words = [
    ['JOSH', 'M', 'WADD', ' ', '41577', '041577'],
    ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', '045211', '045211'],
    ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', '81750', '6161'],
    ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', 'None', '610415770488']
]

stopwords = {' ', 'None'}

for words in lists_of_words:
    print(words)
    # Filter out the words in stopwords.
    filtered = (w for w in words if w not in stopwords)
    # Check which words are in whitelist.
    groups = [w in whitelist for w in filtered]
    print(groups)
    # Find index of first False in groups.
    if False in groups:
        index = groups.index(False)
        print(f"Word at index {index} did not match")
    else:
        print("All words matched.")
```

Here's the output:

```
['JOSH', 'M', 'WADD', ' ', '41577', '041577']
[False, False, True, False, True]
Word at index 0 did not match
['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', '045211', '045211']
[True, True, True, True]
All words matched.
['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', '81750', '6161']
[True, True, True, True]
All words matched.
['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', 'None', '610415770488']
[True, True, False]
Word at index 2 did not match
```

Comment: Thank you @mk12, my bad I was unable to frame the question in a meaningful way

Answer (score 0):

### In this solution, `stopwords` and redundant values are removed from `a` (e.g. `a[1]` as two occurences of `045211`)

```
inp = ['6161', '03901', '81750', 'BRIN', '610415', 'WADD', '045211', '041577']

a = [['JOSH', 'M', 'WADD', ' ', '41577', '041577'],
     ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', '045211', '045211'],
     ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', '81750', '6161'],
     ['BRIN', 'None', 'WADD', 'None', 'None', '610415770488']]

stopwords = [' ','None']

cleaned_a = [list(set(x) - set(stopwords)) for x in a]
```

### output `cleaned_a`:

```
# note that a[1] had 2 occurences of 045211, set only allows unique values
[['041577', '41577', 'WADD', 'JOSH', 'M'],
 ['045211', 'WADD', 'BRIN'],
 ['WADD', '81750', 'BRIN', '6161'],
 ['610415770488', 'WADD', 'BRIN']]
```

### find cases where `inp` is in the `lists` of `cleaned_a`:

#### output `True` or `False`

```
matched_values_true_false = [[z in inp for z in x] for x in cleaned_a]

[[True, False, True, False, False],
 [True, True, True],
 [True, True, True, True],
 [False, True, True]]
```

#### output `1` or `0`

```
matched_values_1_0 = [[int(z in inp) for z in x] for x in cleaned_a]

[[1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 1]]
```

## The original question was, `"I want to identify which all indexes gives output as True..."`:

- using `matched_values_true_false`

#### code:

```
matched_values_index = [[i for i, x in enumerate(y) if x] for y in matched_values_true_false]

[[0, 2],
 [0, 1, 2],
 [0, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2]]
```

- `if x` checks if the value in the list is `True`

  - for the list comprehension above `i` is the index and is only added to the new list, when `x` is `True`

### `matched_values_true_false` and `matched_values_index` can be combined as follows:

```
matched_values_index = [[i for i, q in enumerate(z in inp for z in x) if q] for x in cleaned_a]
```

### Full code to solve the original question is:

```
cleaned_a = [list(set(x) - set(stopwords)) for x in a]
matched_values_index = [[i for i, x in enumerate(y) if x] for y in matched_values]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, unfortunately I cannot mark the answer multiple times. Your solution works great as well!